# Add 15 days to each row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data as shown below (current data)

- ID column is not a primary key
- Requirement is to add 15 days to start date

e.g.

- first row - add 15 days startdate - output 1/30/13
- second row - add 15 days to new date 1/30/13 from first row - output 2/14/14
- third row - add 15 days to new date from second row - output 3/1/13

Modified the `NewDate` column display - is there a way that we can display the `Newdate` column as requested in the desired output dataset?

Current Data

```
ID           NAME       START         END         TRAVELDATE      
===============================================================
1            TOM        1/15/13       12/6/13     1/25/13         
1            TOM        1/15/13       12/6/13     2/2/13          
1            TOM        1/15/13       12/6/13     3/1/13
```

Desired output

```
ID           NAME       START         END         TRAVELDATE      NEWDATE
========================================================================
1            TOM        1/15/13       12/6/13     1/25/13         1/15/13 - 1/30/13
1            TOM        1/15/13       12/6/13     2/2/13          1/30/13 - 2/14/13
1            TOM        1/15/13       12/6/13     3/1/13          2/14/13 - 3/1/13
```

Comment: Is `NEWDATE` a new column? Or do you want to update an existing column?

Comment: It is a new column, that's the requirement to add 15 days to the start date in the first row and then use the output from the firstrow and keep adding 15days.

Comment: How do you know the order of the rows? Traveldate? Does this need to be applied to all rows in the table? (SQL doesn't have inherent ordering of the rows.)

Comment: Does the new date start over for a different name?  I believe the solution will involve the user of the "OVER" syntax.  It may also be able to be handled via a self join on travel date vs min travel date < current travel date and name.

Comment: What column(s) define the order of rows? That only column that looks like it might be usable for this is TRAVELDATE. Assuming you can use that column you can do this with a cte with ROW_NUMBER that joins to itself on RowNum = RowNum - 1 to get the previous row.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and `DATEADD()`:

```
SELECT *,DATEADD(day,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY TravelDate)*15,Start) NewDate
FROM Table1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/597e8d/3/0)

This may need to be tweaked if your sample is not comprehensive, ie if the `Start` date can actually change then you'd want to load the first `Start` value into a variable and use it in the `DATEADD()` function instead of referencing the `Start` value from each row.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response. I appreciate that :)

Comment: Will test the suggestions provided and let you guys know.

Answer (score 1):

Making some test data:

```
DECLARE @Travel TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(20),       
    STARTDT DATE,         
    ENDDT DATE,         
    TRAVELDATE DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Travel
VALUES
(1, 'TOM', '1/15/13', '12/6/13', '1/25/13'),         
(1, 'TOM', '1/15/13', '12/6/13', '2/2/13'),          
(1, 'TOM', '1/15/13', '12/6/13', '3/1/13');
```

Now we use row number to determine our sequence and then use sequence * 15 days for each record:

```
SELECT *,
    DATEADD(DAY, 15 * RN, STARTDT) NEWDATE
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TravelDate) RN
    FROM @Travel
) d
```

Here is the output:

```
ID  NAME    STARTDT ENDDT   TRAVELDATE  RN  NEWDATE
1   TOM 2013-01-15  2013-12-06  2013-01-25  1   2013-01-30
1   TOM 2013-01-15  2013-12-06  2013-02-02  2   2013-02-14
1   TOM 2013-01-15  2013-12-06  2013-03-01  3   2013-03-01
```

Here is the updated revision as requested:

```
SELECT *,
    DATEADD(DAY, 15 * (RN - 1), STARTDT) STARTNEWDATE,
    DATEADD(DAY, 15 * RN, STARTDT) ENDNEWDATE
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TravelDate) RN
    FROM @Travel
) d
```

Here is the revised output:

```
ID  NAME    STARTDT ENDDT   TRAVELDATE  RN  STARTNEWDATE    ENDNEWDATE
1   TOM 2013-01-15  2013-12-06  2013-01-25  1   2013-01-15  2013-01-30
1   TOM 2013-01-15  2013-12-06  2013-02-02  2   2013-01-30  2013-02-14
1   TOM 2013-01-15  2013-12-06  2013-03-01  3   2013-02-14  2013-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great candidate for a recursive CTE.

```
WITH c AS (

SELECT T.ID, NewDate
FROM #Test T

UNION ALL 

SELECT T.ID, DATEADD(DAY, 15, c.NewDate)
FROM #Test T
JOIN c ON c.id =  T.id
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 15, c.NewDate) < '2015-12-31'

)

SELECT * FROM  c
```

Comment: Thank you all!! All your suggestions worked. Unfortunately I can't vote since I don't have minimum reputations.                         +1 for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
SELECT ID,NAME,START,[END],TRAVELDATE
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY TRAVELDATE) as rowNo
, DATEADD(DAY,15,START) as newDate
INTO #TEMP
FROM START


;WITH c AS(
SELECT ID,NAME,START,[END],TRAVELDATE, NEWDATE, rowNo
FROM #TEMP T
where T.rowNo = 1
UNION ALL
    SELECT t.ID,t.NAME,t.START,t.[END],t.TRAVELDATE, DATEADD(DAY,15,c.NEWDATE) as newDate, t.rowNo
    FROM #TEMP T
    JOIN c ON T.rowNo = c.rowNo+1
    AND T.NAME = c.NAME

)
SELECT * FROM c
ORDER BY c.NAME, c.rowNo
```

This works well if you have multiple names and you want to start from the start date of each name.

See [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13cae/8) for more info.